Installing cisco webex on ubuntu 24.04
I already have installed ubuntu webex on ubuntu 24.04, but dont open:
app-gnome-webex-21510.scope: Couldn't move process 21510 to requested cgroup '/user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/app.slice/app-gnome-webex-21510.scope': No such process
nov 12 12:53:19 liudmila-bisnext systemd[14294]: app-gnome-webex-21510.scope: Failed to add PIDs to scope's control group: No such process
nov 12 12:53:19 liudmila-bisnext systemd[14294]: app-gnome-webex-21510.scope: Failed with result 'resources'.
nov 12 12:53:19 liudmila-bisnext systemd[14294]: Failed to start app-gnome-webex-21510.scope - Application launched by gnome-shell.

Some one coul hep me
